# double bar notation and squared meaning?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

[image]

in the multivariate Gaussian related problem, there is a step like this
where xi is a d dimensional vector, μ is the mean vector, so I know the difference between L2 norm and L1 norm, but I just don't understand why the above equation is equal??

Comment: The dot product of a vector with itself equals the vector’s magnitude squared

Comment: What @J.W.Tanner said, and also, note that $x_i-\mu_k$ only appears atomically (never broken up into smaller pieces), and it can be replaced by any term: $v^T v = || v ||$.